# Case-insensitive query criteria with MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I have a query criteria which looks for an array of elements ( tags_array ) to match :

```
User.all_in('watchlists.tags_array' => tags_array)
```

I'd like the criteria to be CASE-INSENSITIVE, meaning I want it match `%w[Ruby Web Framework]` as well as `%w[RUBY WEB FRAMEWORK]` or `%w[ruby web framework]` and so on ...

Is this possible via mongoid or do I have to use external filter tricks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [the support of Jordan](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!topic/mongoid/oa47I51Pb78) and just for tracking purposes (for myself and others as well), I'll post the entire solution.

Yes, [Yuriy Goldshtrakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397364/yuriy-goldshtrakh) was right, MongoDB still does not support case-insensitive query but MongoID has regex, my only doubt is regarding performance degradation as already said by "[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)" but I didn't check until now ... anyway here it is :

```
 Object.const_set :Competitor, Struct.new(:html_url, :description, :watchers, :forks)
 def self.find_competitors(tags_array)
    competitors = []
    User.all_in('watchlists.tags_array' => tags_array.map{|tag|/^#{tag}/i}).only(:watchlists).each do |u|
     u.watchlists.all_in(:tags_array => tags_array.map{|tag|/^#{tag}/i}).desc(:watchers).each do |wl|
       competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
     end
    end
    return competitors
 end
```

No normalization at save/create mongoid level, the tags are saved either upper or lower case.

Normalization (case-insensitive matching of tags) are realized entirely during the nested quering criteria ( it's nested because of [embedded one to many model](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html) ).

If you have better idea or code, please have a post.

I'd also thanks [Luiz K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587406/luiz-k) for answering, even if I'll not follow that way: normalization at data level is too restrictive in my view, loosing semantic and elasticity "user" side (who actually is tagging). Anyway could be a good solution for other requirements.

Many thanks
Luca G. Soave

Answer (score 4):

I don't think mongo has support for the non case-sensitive selects, you can either normalize the data by converting it all to a specific case or use regexp finders

Comment: A regex search would be expensive, better to store a downcased copy and search that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've done:

```
def create
    @noticia = Noticia.new(params[:noticia])
    @noticia.tags = @noticia.conteudo.html_safe.split(' ')
    @noticia.tags.each_with_index do |tag, index|
      @noticia.tags[index] = @noticia.tags[index].gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "")
    end
```

i've splitted all noticia's content into 'tags', and downcased they. in my search i do the following:

```
def buscar
    array = params[:query].split(' ')
    array.each_with_index do |query, index|
      array[index] = array[index].gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "").downcase
    end
    @noticias = Noticia.where(:tags.all => array).paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
```

i've downcased my query search too
don't forget to index `tags` field

Answer (score 0):

In order to managing regexp in mongo request (find , update..)
I do this:
'p' is a variable that stores the name to search

```
 reg =  /^#{p}$/i
 @db['pgm'].update({'nom' => reg }....
```